# Controlling scroll position on postback

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to control the scroll position on postback in SharePoint 2010?

I have a web part that I want the users to be special position of the page after a postback on a button click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Navigate to your Default.Master Page in Sharepoint Designer and add the following Line:

```
<%@ Page Language=”C#” AutoEventWireup=”true” MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=”true” %>
```

Step 2: Save and publish your Default.Master Page, you will notice that Sharepoint Designer has modified the above line to something like the following (Depending on your Sharepoint Version):

```
<%@ Page Language=”C#” AutoEventWireup=”true” MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=”true” inherits=”Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c” %>
```

Step 3: Add # anchor tags as per normal HTML to your Web Part Pages and your Scroll Position will be maintained on Postback

Answer referred from [this post](http://www.applogix.co.za/blog/index.php/2011/01/sharepoint-maintain-scroll-position-on-postback/#comments)

If that does not help, check [this post from msdn](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sharepoint2010programming/thread/f6c5d7e4-a977-49c0-8d31-f619c4bdca7c) which implements it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HTML by specifying an anchor tag, giving it a name and then appending the # to the end of the Url when doing the postback. :)

Alternatively you can use javascript when the page loads and have a hidden field with the anchor to scroll to.